# Windows 10 cut file stops working, copy works (with one issue), move works

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Total issues I can see:

- if I Ctrl + X after selecting a file, the file icon "grays" for a fraction of a second and then
  "un-grays" immediately
- same if I right-click and select "Cut"
- if I Ctrl-V or right-click "Paste" anywhere *other than* that location, it will paste the file as if I had done a Copy
- if I Ctrl-V or right-click "Paste" at that location, I get a "Interrupted Action" pop-up box that essentially gives me no ability to do the thing where you can paste the file at the same location and it automatically just makes a "[file name] - Copy.extension" version (very useful!). It won't do that anymore. I have to Copy the file somewhere else, edit it's name, and then Move it back
- I can Move files with no issues
- if I copy the file to somewhere and then attempt to Move it back to that location, I get the usual "Replace or Skip" pop-up that you would more often expect
- no issues with cutting or copying text in text files.

Tried to make a .gif to show these, unfortunately the "gray" blips so fast it didn't record.

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions?? I've tried everything that you get from Googling things like "Windows cut copy no longer working" and none of it works.

Restart will fix it, but eventually it dies again. And it seems like it is dying faster and faster lately. I've tried turning on clipboard history but I never know what actually causes it, so I never know for sure which entry is the culprit.

I have Power Toys installed and I'm not giving that up, Fancy Zones and keyboard shortcut remapping are too important. I've updated it to the latest and that doesn't fix anything.

There is all kinds of 3rd-party stuff on here that work requires. But no one I've talked to here has ever heard of this issue before (nor had I).

Comment: That looks like the folder is write protected (or maybe corrupted). Check in properties-> permissions

Comment: Also, scan your disk for errors as described here: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-sfc-scannow-command-fix-problems-windows-10

Comment: @1NN thanks for the comments. But if something like those are the issue, then why is it whenever I start it all works just fine for some unknown/random(?) amount of time *and then* dies?

I have "full control" on all folders, so I don't think it is permissions.

Comment: @1NN I ran sfc /scannow in elevated cmd and it claimed it found and repaired corrupted files. I tried to examine the log file but the heck if I can decypher it. Tried searching for 'corrupt' and got nothing, searched for 'repair' and got too many things. I will restart and cross my fingers that this goes away, but I am not hopeful. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @1NN nope, it already died. I think this is a record, I hadn't even opened File Explorer (or whatever it is called in 10) yet! Do you have any other suggestions? Thank you

Comment: @leka0024: SFC repairs are not guaranteed to fully fix a Windows corruption. I suggest doing a [Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: @harrymc I will have to ask IT about that, I'm not sure I have that option. I'm also afraid about losing all my unsaved work. And that it would cost a bunch of time ... only to not fix it. 

I just don't get this. How can this happen?? Has anyone ever seen this before?? (Wish the gif would show it, but the description I gave is really what happens).

Comment: We don't have any problem with your problem description. Repair Install is the same as doing a major Windows update and should keep your data, apps and settings. But in an imperfect world, backups are always recommended.